# Why does this regex cause my program to crash?

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio-2010

I was writing a regex to extract a directory and filename. I tested it in a regex tester and it seems to work there, but when I run it in my C++ program it crashes.

```
regex re("^(.*)(\\/|\\\)(.*\\.flt)$");
```

I'm compiling with Visual Studio 2010 SP1. When I run the code it breaks on the line given above. Why?

Edit: The exception I get is

> Microsoft C++ exception: std::tr1::regex_error at memory location
>   0x0042eb4c.

And it breaks at line 19 of regex.cpp

Comment: Define "it crashes" and "it breaks". We can't help you unless you tell us what is happening. You wouldn't expect the coroner to write for cause of death, "he died".

Comment: You might miss a '\' at '| \ \ \ )'

Comment: Use [c++ raw string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) for regular expressions. They'll make your life a lot easier. _"Visual Studio 2010 SP1"_ Do you really need to use such an old compiler to realize your code?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Updated.

Comment: @Dieter Lücking:  Yes that was it, thanks.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: Yes, that would be better - I didn't know you could do that :)

Comment: @UltimateGobblement With VS2010 I'm afraid you can't :-( ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are escaping the backslash incorrectly:

```
(\\/|\\\)
```

which is supposed to mean "a forward or a back slash" is going to be transformed by the compiler first. Each pair of characters that starts in a backslash will be replaced by a single character based on the escape sequence.

`\\` is a valid escape sequence representing `\`. `\)`, however, is not a valid escape sequence, so it would be replaced by `)`. Therefore, regex constructor is going to "see" this:

```
(\/|\)
```

This escapes the closing parenthesis, resulting in syntax error.

Character classes provide a better syntax for your situation: instead of parenthesized "OR" group, use a single

```
[/\\\\]
```

After C++ replaces escape sequences, regex constructor will see this construct,

```
[/\\]
```

which means "a forward or a back slash".